# Switch tag inside for loop is generating an error

Tags: twig

I have the following code:

```
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<div class="container">
    {% for section, setting_data in settings %}
        <h4>{{section|title}}</h4>
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Value</th>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            {% for setting_name, setting in setting_data %}
                <tr>
                    <td>{{setting_name}}</td>
                    <td>
                        {% switch setting.display_type %}
                            {% case constant('\\Settings::DISPLAY_INPUT') %}
                                <input type="text" name="settings[{{setting.setting_id}}]" value="{{setting.value}}" />
                            {% case constant('\\Settings::DISPLAY_CHECKBOX') %}
                                <input type="hidden" name="settings[{{setting.setting_id}}]" value="" />
                                <input type="checkbox" name="settings[{{setting.setting_id}}]" value="1" {%if setting.value=="Y"%}checked="checked"{%endif%} />
                            {% case constant('\\Settings::DISPLAY_TEXT') %}
                                <textarea name="settings[{{setting.setting_id}}]">{{setting.value}}</textarea
                        {%endswitch%}   
                    </td>
                <tr>
<pre>section={{section}}, setting_name={{setting_name}}, setting:{{name}}={{setting.value}}</pre>
            {%endfor%}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    {%endfor%}
</div>
```

However it is generating an error (below).  If I comment out the switch and replace it with {{setting.value}} all displays fine.  Any thoughts?

> Fatal error: Uncaught Twig\Error\SyntaxError: Unexpected "switch" tag
> (expecting closing tag for the "for" tag defined near line 12). in
> /home/birnseth/hotline/templates/backend/settings/edit.twig:15 Stack
> trace: #0
> /home/birnseth/hotline/vendor/twig/twig/src/TokenParser/ForTokenParser.php(52):
> Twig\Parser->subparse(Array) #1
> /home/birnseth/hotline/vendor/twig/twig/src/Parser.php(185):
> Twig\TokenParser\ForTokenParser->parse(Object(Twig\Token)) #2
> /home/birnseth/hotline/vendor/twig/twig/src/TokenParser/ForTokenParser.php(52):
> Twig\Parser->subparse(Array) #3
> /home/birnseth/hotline/vendor/twig/twig/src/Parser.php(185):
> Twig\TokenParser\ForTokenParser->parse(Object(Twig\Token)) #4
> /home/birnseth/hotline/vendor/twig/twig/src/Parser.php(98):
> Twig\Parser->subparse(NULL, false) #5
> /home/birnseth/hotline/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(563):
> Twig\Parser->parse(Object(Twig\TokenStream)) #6
> /home/birnseth/hotline/vendor/twig/twig/src/Environment.php(595):
> Twig\Environment->parse(Object(Twig\TokenStream)) #7
> /home/birnseth/hotli in
> /home/birnseth/hotline/templates/backend/settings/edit.twig on line 15

Comment: You error is a parser error, so Twig can't correctly match start & end tags meaning you have invalid HTML. Your `textarea` end tag misses a `>` at the end.

Comment: `switch` is not a tag in twig by default

Comment: webketje - Resolved the closing tag, did not make a difference

Comment: DarkBee - Yes, guess it's not in the version I'm running (v2.14.7).  Unfortunate since the code is so much more readable  Doesn't like {% if arg == constant('\\MyClass::FOO') %} either.  I should have stuck with Smarty.  Much more feature rich and you can use real operators.